# Problems converting Docker run to Kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am having some trouble converting my docker setup to kubernetes. I have read the kubectl for docker users, have set up minikube and am trying to autoscale my docker application with kubernetes.
But I am having some trouble just running it.

I am trying to make a container with a python flask application on centos image that uses a database that I have setup in the cloud

In docker I would just use the docker build . -tag and then use docker run to setup my container. like so:

[image]

This would give me a container on port 5000 (For the Database I have to use the hostnetwork als it needs an ip to work with. setting localhost 127.0.0.1:5000 doesnt seem to work, but that is another issue in itself)

When I read the Kubectl documentation for docker users it would seem like i can do almost the same I do with docker in Kubernetes. So I am trying this.

I haven't figured out how to use --network host in kubernetes but I thought just running it and see if it gave an error. And it did. It seems not to be able to pull the image. but docker can. What is going wrong here?
[image]

after a while it just goes to.

[image]

I haven't even tried horizontal autoscaling yet, nor do I understand the docker-file convert yet. But i should be able to just run the container right?

EDIT:
I used windows to generate the screenshots.

**Commands I am running:**

docker run --network host -d hu-simple:latest

**output I am getting:**

a docker deamon string because it created a docker container for me

**Commands in Kubernetes I am trying:**

kubectl run --image=hu-simpel:latest hu-simpel --port=5000

**output i am getting:**

deployment.apps/hu-simpel created

**But when I try kubectl get all:**

I get: ErrImagepull and ImagePullBackOff after a while.

I don't think I am using a kubernetes deployment yaml as I am just trying to run a docker image on kubernetes. I didnt create it in kubernetes using a docker-compose but just tried to run the docker image. But do tell me if I am mistaken.

Comment: What generates these PNG files?  Can you edit your question to include, as text, the actual commands you're running and the output you're getting?  A relevant fragment of your Kubernetes deployment YAML file would be helpful as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have edited the question. Although I didnt seem to get the kubernetes deployment yaml question. I used a docker image and tried to run it on kubernetes I didn't create the container in kubernetes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your minikube instance is not able to reach your Docker daemon. In other words, your Kubernetes doesn't know anything about the images you built using your host Docker.

To solve this, you have this command: `minikube docker-env`. This will export everything from Docker to your minikube instance, meaning that you'll be able to reuse the images you build in your host.

When you finish you can do `docker-machine env -u`.

Comment: I seem to get the "'none' driver does not support 'minikube docker-env' command" error. Thought maybe using --vm-driver=docker would help but it didn't still got the same error.

Comment: Do you mean you created your minikube with `minikube start --vm-driver=none`?  You can try with `minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox` (this is the default in most of the cases). The none driver is more aimed for working with minikube in a custom VM provided by you. You can have a look here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/
The VirtualBox driver will basically provision a VirtualBox virtual machine (hah) with your minikube running inside.

Comment: Yes i did, the minikube is in a vm itself so I read that you should use -vm-driver=none in those cases

Comment: Docker is also in the VM, right? Maybe you can try running your pods with `kubectl run --image=hu-simpel:latest hu-simpel --port=5000 --image-pull-policy=Never`

Comment: This worked! thanks. can you tell me what the option does and can I use the same option if I will work with kubernetes yaml files in the future?

Comment: `imagePullPolicy` has three possible configs: `Never` is to use always an image present locally, `IfNotPresent` tries to use one locally or pulls, and `Always` that always pulls. You can include that in your YAML: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images

Comment: Thanks again! and thank you for explaining. it will save me a lot of headaches in the future.